# How do I see which apps are running?

Tags: unity, launcher

How do I see which apps are running? I'd like to see what's running in the panel and not let go of the mouse to use a keyboard shortcut. Can Unity be configured?

Comment: you can simply use-> ps  -u  [username]

Answer (score 8):

In Unity there are admittedly subtle but clearly visible indicators on the Launcher that show a running application, and the active window:

[image: Screenshot showing launcher indicators]

In addition, in 11.04 and above, when there are multiple windows for that app you will see multiple pips (2, or 3 for 3-or-more windows).

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you mean well, you can command top to see what the program running.

```
terminal ->top
```

Comment: Also try `htop`, it provides much clearer output and it's interface is much more user-friendly.

Answer (score 2):

You can also see what applications are running with system monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Use the System Monitor. Go to "view" and tick on "All processes" and "Dependencies" 
If you want a windows like process explorer then you can use "linux process explorer"

Download Link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/procexp/

Answer (score 0):

- you can see the processes running by following command

> $ ps

- if want to see the processes running by particular user

```
 $ ps -u [username]
```

eg: $ps -u ubuntu